# Pointers & converting a char array to an int

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, byte

I am doing some exercises to figure out how to access values in an array after they are changed with pointers.  Can someone point out why the first output does not show the desired output? I am trying to get both cout to print 1234, one by using the new pointer and one by using the position in the array

```
int main()
{
    char myArray[50]={0};
    short* sizeOfAlloc=(short*)(myArray+5);  
         *sizeOfAlloc=1234;

    cout << (short*)(myArray+5) <<endl; 
    cout << *sizeOfAlloc <<endl;
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: In the first line, you don't dereference.

Comment: myArray is a `char**` but you cast it to a `short*`. 2 problems: 1. (the main one), you have changed the level of indirection. 2. You have cast from `char` to `short`, which you should only do if you really know what you're doing (more likely you want to cast to `int16_t`)

Comment: Thank you Daniel and Dave.  Regarding your first comment dave, do you know of a better way to convert some chars to a double or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout << (short*)(myArray+5) <<endl;
```

Prints the pointer.  Not the value pointed by it.

```
cout << *((short*)(myArray+5)) <<endl;
        ^^                   ^^
```

Will print the value pointed to by `(short*)(myArray+5)`

Comment: @stardust_: If this helped resolve your issue, mark this as the answer.

Comment: @ViteFalcon How? :) he asked the question. Not me :)

Comment: @stardust_: I meant user2012481. Sorry :)